# String to Data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 column in data frame, X and Y. And I have some string values stored in text, which I want to put in X, Y as shown in the example.

Example :

```
text=9 10 13 110 14 16
     12 1 6   1  1  2
```

```
X    Y

9    12

10   1

13   6

110  1

14   1

16   2
```

Comment: Could you please explain more what you want to do?

Comment: I want to create a data frame  from list  for digits . I have 2 column X and Y . in X I want to put all the 1st digits  9 ,10, 13, 110, 14, 16 and in Y I want to put   12, 1, 6   1 , 1,  2  so that  both value of X map correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to hard-code it for only 2 columns, this can be achieved as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

text = '9 10 13 110 14 16 12 1 6   1  1  2'
text = text.split()

df['X'] = text[:int(len(text)/2)]
df['Y'] = text[int(len(text)/2):]
```

Comment: 9 10 13 110 14 16
12 1 6   1  1  2     . These numbers are stored in  a variable called text . I have to put in X and Y accordingly .

Comment: text=9 10 13 110 14 16
     12 1 6   1  1  2   .  these are the digits . I want to create a data frame , in X column I want to put  9 , 10 , 13, 110, 14, 16 and in Y = 12 1 6   1  1  2

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your text is in two strings like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                            

In [2]: text1 = "9 10 13 110 14 16"                                                                    

In [3]: text2 = "12 1 6 1 1 2"
```

A one-liner solution would be:

```
In [4] df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip(text1.split(" "), text2.split(" ")))
```

A Pandas Dataframe can be created by passing it one list (or tuple) for each row that you want in the table. This is done by using the `from_records()` method you see above.

So the steps that make the above line work:

1. `split()` each string on the spaces, to get a list of strings - one per value.
2. create each row that we want in the dataframe, which is each matched pair from the two lists of values. `zip` does exactly that for us.
3. Put the result into the `from_records()` method.

The final result:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:

0   1
0    9  12
1   10   1
2   13   6
3  110   1
4   14   1
5   16   2
```

Because we just gave the dataframe lists of strings, the values are still strings in teh dataframe. If you want to actually use them as number, you can use the `astype()` method, like this

```
df_integers = df.astype(int)    # now contains integers
df_floats = df.astype(float)    # now contains floats, i.e. decimal values
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, the solution should be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
text = "9 10 13 110 14 16 12 1 6 1 1 2"
text = text.split()
X_part = text[:int(len(text)/2)]
Y_part = text[int(len(text)/2):]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y'])
df['X'] = X_part
df['Y'] = Y_part
```

Output:[image]